# Inserção dinâmica conforme data e dias da semana

Tags: php, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Estou criando uma aplicação usando *webservice* em PHP. Dentro da aplicação o usuário definirá dias específicos para gerar uma alerta, por exemplo:

- segunda
- quarta
- sexta

Desta forma, gostaria que meu banco registra-se um evento toda, segunda, quarta e sexta sucessivamente toda semana, e mostrasse na *timeline* do usuário. Eu não sei se tenho que fazer `triggers`(não sei se é possível) na base de dados ou um serviço em PHP. Alguém pode me esclarecer um pouco?!

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como criar evento diario no Mysql 5.6?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/41467/como-criar-evento-diario-no-mysql-5-6)

Answer (score 3):

Você pode criar um `Event Scheduler` no banco de dados.
Primeiro habilite o recurso:

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

ou

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = 1;
```

Depois crie o evento. No caso a seguir o evento é executado diariamente e insere um registro na tabela `ALERTA`:

```
CREATE EVENT novoEvento
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
DO
INSERT INTO alerta(descricao) values('ALERTA');
```

Para mostrar todos os eventos:

```
SHOW EVENTS;
```

---

> [**23.4 Using the Event Scheduler**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html)
>
> The MySQL Event Scheduler manages the scheduling and execution of events, that is, tasks that run according to a schedule.

Em tradução livre:

> O Agendador de Eventos do MySQL gerencia o agendamento e execução de eventos, que são, tarefas que executam de acordo com o agendamento.

Comment: Parece ser uma resposta válida. Vou tentar pesquisar um pouco mais sobre o event_scheduler e valido sua resposta. Abs.

Comment: Ainda não fiz o teste, não cheguei nessa parte do meu projeto. =)

Comment: @Viana Conseguiu testar?

Comment: @Sorack pelo jeito você é bem paciente, deixou 2 anos de intervalo para tentar de novo :D

Comment: @Bacco hahahaha vai que o projeto é longo e ele só estava se adiantando...

Comment: @Bacco kkkkkkk chorei

Comment: @Sorack e é possível saber qual dia da semana é com o `CREATE EVENT`?