# Como executar query na virada do dia?

Tags: mysql

Gostaria de saber se há algum gatilho ou processo que eu possa na virada do dia `00:00` mudar status de parcelas que tem suas respectivas datas de vencimento maiores que `hoje()`. Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Não há como existir algo tão específico assim, mas você pode programar um job para ser executado nesse horário, dê uma pesquisada sobre jobs no mysql.

Comment: Relacionada: [Inserção dinâmica conforme data e dias da semana](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/163589/inser%C3%A7%C3%A3o-din%C3%A2mica-conforme-data-e-dias-da-semana)

Comment: Talvez uma outra solução seria utilizando [Cronjob](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21196785/3096922)

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar um recurso do `MySql`chamado `Event`. De maneira simplória um `Event` é um `script` que você configura para rodar de tempos em tempos.

O evento abaixo será executado todos os dias às 00:20, a data informada é a data a partir do dia em que o evento irá iniciar...

```
CREATE EVENT nome_evento
   ON SCHEDULE 
     EVERY 1 DAY
     STARTS '2016-06-12 00:20:00' ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE
  DO
    #AÇÃO A SER REALIZADA
```

Sugiro as seguintes leituras:

[Artigo Percona](https://www.percona.com/blog/2015/02/25/using-mysql-event-scheduler-and-how-to-prevent-contention/)

[Documentação MySql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html)

[Fonte do Exemplo](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/64208)

Comment: Não esquece que tem que habilitar o recurso na base de dados com `SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;`

Comment: @Sorack é verdade... srrsrsrs

Comment: !!!!Obrigado!!!!