# Como fazer um loop no Mysql com base em uma consulta

Tags: mysql, sql

Gostaria de saber se é possível criar um evento no banco de dados MySql, onde a cada 5 minutos o banco faz uma consulta, onde retorna todos os ids dos pedidos e com base em cada id eu realize outra consulta e o resultado dessa consulta, inserir em outra tabela do banco de dados.

[image: Consulta que retorna todos os ids]


A cada id acima, realizar essa consulta abaixo subtituindo o **order_id** do **WHERE orders.order_id LIKE order_id** por cada id da consulta acima.

`SELECT 
    orders.order_id,
    orders.user_id,
    orders.email,
    products.url,
    SUM(plugin_table.product_unavailable) AS product_unavailable,
    SUM(plugin_table.added_to_cart) AS added_to_cart,
    SUM(plugin_table.ordered) AS ordered,
    SUM(plugin_table.plugin_imported) AS plugin_imported,
    SUM(plugin_table.price) AS price,
    SUM(plugin_table.recommendation_done) AS recommendation_done,
    SUM(plugin_table.recommended_size) AS recommended_size,
    SUM(plugin_table.plugin_opened) AS plugin_opened
FROM
    new_intelligence.aggr_orders orders
        JOIN
    new_intelligence.aggr_products products
        JOIN
    new_intelligence.raw_plugin_usage plugin_table 
FORCE INDEX 
    (SESSION_USER) ON plugin_table.product_id = products.product_id
WHERE orders.order_id LIKE order_id
    AND plugin_table.domain = orders.domain
    AND plugin_table.user_id = orders.user_id
GROUP BY products.url;`


E o resultado da consulta acima inserir numa outra tabela.

Comment: Edite a sua questão e coloque o código que está a usar para tentar chegar à solução.

Comment: Relacionada: [Inserção dinâmica conforme data e dias da semana](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/163589/inser%C3%A7%C3%A3o-din%C3%A2mica-conforme-data-e-dias-da-semana/163593#163593)

Answer (score 0):

Não entendi direito o que você precisa fazer com o loop, mas você poderia utilizar algum CURSOR numa PROCEDURE, já que você precisaria percorrer o resultado de uma consulta.

Sobre o evento você pode criar um dessa forma

```
DELIMITER $

CREATE EVENT `ev_nome_event`
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 MINUTE
    STARTS '2019-03-02 00:05:00'
    ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE COMMENT 'Comentário'
    DO BEGIN
        -- Chamar a procedure que fará todo o processo;
    END$
```

Após criar o evento, você tem que se certificar que a variável event_scheduler esteja ON, você pode verificar utilizando:

```
SHOW VARIABLES;
```

E para ligar os eventos:

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Acabei resolvendo esse problema da seguindo forma: 


Obs: Estou utilizando o MySQL 5.6

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE EVENT aggr_all_details_of_orders  

ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 MINUTE STARTS NOW() 

ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE COMMENT 'Join all order details and 
insert in the table aggr_all_orders_details' 

DO BEGIN

    DECLARE id_orders varchar(250);
    DECLARE order_domain varchar(250);
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;

    DECLARE cursor_order_detail CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT order_id, domain FROM new_intelligence.aggr_orders;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    OPEN cursor_order_detail;

        run_orders: LOOP

            FETCH cursor_order_detail INTO id_orders, order_domain;

                IF done THEN
                    LEAVE run_orders;
                END IF;

                INSERT INTO new_intelligence.aggr_all_orders_details
                (
                 order_id,
                 product_id,
                 user_id, 
                 session_id,
                 email,
                 domain,
                 update_date,
                 recommended_size,
                 price,
                 recommendation_done,
                 product_unavailable, 
                 added_to_cart,
                 ordered,
                 plugin_imported,
                 plugin_opened
                )
                SELECT 
                    orders.order_id,
                    products.product_id,
                    orders.user_id,
                    orders.session_id,
                    orders.email,
                    orders.domain,
                    orders.update_date,
                    GROUP_CONCAT(plugin_table.recommended_size SEPARATOR ';') AS recommended_size,
                    SUM(plugin_table.price) AS price,
                    IF( SUM(plugin_table.recommendation_done) > 0, 1, 0) AS recommendation_done,
                    IF( SUM(plugin_table.product_unavailable) > 0, 1, 0) AS product_unavailable,
                    IF( SUM(plugin_table.added_to_cart) > 0, 1, 0) AS added_to_cart,
                    IF( SUM(plugin_table.ordered) > 0, 1, 0) AS ordered,
                    IF( SUM(plugin_table.plugin_imported) > 0, 1, 0) AS plugin_imported,
                    IF( SUM(plugin_table.plugin_opened) > 0, 1, 0) AS plugin_opened
                FROM
                    new_intelligence.aggr_orders orders
                        JOIN
                    new_intelligence.aggr_products products
                        JOIN
                    new_intelligence.raw_plugin_usage plugin_table FORCE INDEX (SESSION_USER) ON plugin_table.product_id = products.product_id
                WHERE
                orders.order_id LIKE id_orders
                AND plugin_table.domain = orders.domain
                AND plugin_table.user_id = orders.user_id
                AND orders.domain = order_domain
                GROUP BY products.url; 

        END LOOP;

    CLOSE cursor_order_detail;

    DEALLOCATE PREPARE cursor_order_detail;

    END |

    DELIMITER ;
```