# dúvida com data em tabelas sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, trigger

bom, eu tenho uma tabela com as seguintes informações

```
usernum  /  type  /  expiredate
   1         1      2019-03-03 13:04:42.710
```

o que eu queria fazer é ter um gatilho nessa tabela que verificasse a data e quando essa data vencesse alterasse esse type pra outro valor e alterasse a data pra um novo dia tambem, por exemplo, quando vencesse essa data ai ficasse assim:

```
usernum  /  type  /  expiredate
   1         0      2019-03-20 13:04:42.710
```

Comment: Desculpe perguntar mas porque você não usa o `now()` na própria query ?

Comment: me desculpe mas eu sou leigo ainda, como faço pra usar esse now()

Comment: Por exemplo quando for altear o type, vocÊ deve executar uma query assim `update tabela set type = 0 where id usernum` no lugar disso você poderia usar `update tabela set type = 0, expiredate = now() where id usernum` com isso a data vai pegar a hora exata do update

Comment: @Bulfaitelo na realidade ele não quer uma `trigger`. Ele quer que altere automaticamente quando vencer

Comment: @Sorack Verdade eu entendi o contrario.

Comment: eu vi um pessoal comentando em outra dúvida parecida para montar um job que verifique a cada n minutos, mas nao sei como fazer

Comment: @Merlin Normalmente esse tipo de coisa eu faria na minha aplicação, por exemplo com uso do crontab ou agendador de tarefas do windows

Comment: @Merlin logo após o almoço redijo uma resposta

Comment: @Sorack muitíssimo obrigado pela atenção

Comment: a você também @Bulfaitelo

Comment: Relacionada: [Inserção dinâmica conforme data e dias da semana](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/163589/inser%C3%A7%C3%A3o-din%C3%A2mica-conforme-data-e-dias-da-semana/163593#163593)

Comment: Você usa o sql ou mysql server?

Comment: @LeticiaRosa sql server 2008

Comment: @Merlin você não pode apenas criar uma view e trazer essa valor preenchido de acordo com a data?

Comment: @Merlin acabei de postar uma resposta para o sql server

Answer (score 1):

A trigger só funciona quando você realiza uma ação no banco de dados (insert, update, delete...). Creio que a melhor solução no seu caso seria um agendamento da tarefa.

No SQL Server você pode usar o SQL Server Agent para realizar agendamentos. Esse serviço não está disponível em versões do SQL EXPRESS. Se essa for sua versão você pode usar o Agendador de Tarefas do Windows para agendar uma bat que rode o seu script do SQL.

**Situação 1 - SQL Server Agent**
Você precisa primeiro ativar o serviço. Como fazer isso:

> 1. Clique em Iniciar, clique em Programas e, em seguida, clique em SQL Server 2008.
>
>    2. Clique em Ferramentas de Configuração e, em seguida, clique em SQL Server Configuration Manager.
>    3. Expanda os serviços do SQL Server 2008.
>    4. Localize o serviço SQL Server Agent. O serviço SQL Server Agent é denominado "SQL Server Agent" para instâncias padrão e "SQL Server
>         Agent (nome da instância)" para instâncias nomeadas.
>    5. Clique em SQL Server Agent e, em seguida, clique em Propriedades.
>    6. Na guia Logon , clique para selecionar a caixa de seleção esta conta . Especifique um nome de conta diferente e uma senha.
>    7. Na seção status do serviço , clique em Iniciar e, em seguida, clique em Ok.

Depois do serviço iniciado você precisar criar o Job. Para isso vá no Management Studio e, em Object Explorer (aba lateral onde tem o banco e as tabelas) você terá a opção SQL Server Agent e lá poderá criar um novo job.

**Situação 2 - Versão Express do SQL SERVER**

Se você utilizar a versão Express do SQL SERVER o SQL Server Agent não irá iniciar. Para rodar o seu script então você pode usar o agendador de tarefas para fazer esse serviço para você "manualmente"

Para isso crie um arquivo .bat com o seguinte comando:

```
sqlcmd -i script.sql
```

Na mesma pasta salve o arquivo script.sql com o código SQL que você deseja rodar. Depois, crie uma tarefa no agendador de tarefas do Windows que rode essa bat todos os dias em um horário específico.

Um comando que você pode usar para realizar essa tarefa de adicionar mais tempo na data, pelo seu exemplo, é o [DATEADD()](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) que soma um valor inteiro a uma parte da data de sua escolha.