# Criando evento no Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Gostaria de criar um evento baseado em 2 situações.

Tenho uma tabela e a coluna a 
situacao_id com os valores

> [1 - livre],  [2 - ocupado],  [3 - Indisponível];

E outra coluna modificado -  gera a data da modificação do cadastro.

O evento deve ocorrer da seguinte forma.

Executar o evento todo o dia pelas 5 horas da manhã.

Se o situacao_id for = 2 - pegar o valor da modificação(data) > 3 dias.
UPDATE TABLE situacao_id retornar ao valor 1.

Mas não sei como criar o evento desta forma.

E criar o evento que se a data de cadastro for > 6 meses dar um DELETE na tabela.

Não sei iniciar os comandos para criar os eventos no mysql.

---

**Solução:**
A partir do Mysql 5.1 existe eventos que podemos executar ações no MYSQL.

Fazemos uma alteração na situação do cadastro do usuário.
Um cadastro após 3 dias da data de modificação, retorna a situação disponível.

Pelo painel PHPmyAdmin clicando no banco nas abas temos EVENTOS.

Clicando ali podemos criar eventos que podem ser por minutos, horas, dias, semanas.

Pode ser executado 1 única vez como "One Time" ou recurring, sendo executado como Execute every, informando como dia ou semana ou meses, etc...

Nas definições inserimos a execução no mysql
Que no meu caso seria assim:

```
UPDATE cadastros SET situacao_id = '1' WHERE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), modified) > 3;
```

Executando, todo o dia as 5 horas da manhã verifica todos os cadastros, se a data de modificação for superior a 3 dias ele faz o update da situação para 1 Livre.

Comment: O problema é a execução do php todo dia pelas 5 horas da manhã. Quem vai rodar o script todo dia a essa hora?

Comment: Você vai ter que criar um CRON para rodar um script no PHP para fazer isso. No CRON você pode definir ele para roda todos os dias a qualquer hora.

Comment: Tem uma documentação, não sei se procede pois não entendo ingles   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo e @Kayo, não precisa de CRON, o evento no mysql é setado a ser executado todo os dias, é um evento de rotina que o mysql faz a partir da versão 5.1, vc cria o evento para ele ser executado sempre todo o dia.
`CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` EVENT `Muda_status` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2017-06-16 11:38:00' ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE DO UPDATE `curriculos` SET `situacao_id`= 1´
Os termos EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2017-06-16 11:38:00' ON - significa todos os dias iniciando '2017-06-16 11:38:00'

Comment: @Marcelo Rossi valeu, nunca tinha ouvido falar disso, novidade para mim!

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo eu estou estudando essa documentação, mas não estou conseguindo criar o evento baseado na minha necessidade, por isso estou pedindo ajuda.

Comment: Veja se esse post ajuda  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070277/mysql-event-scheduler-on-a-specific-time-everyday

Comment: mais em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/41467/como-criar-evento-diario-no-mysql-5-6

Comment: http://respostas.guj.com.br/28429-como-criar-um-evento-limpar-tabela-mysql-todos-os-dias

Comment: Estou tentando fazer assim no evento: `UPDATE `curriculos` set `situacao_id` = 1, `modified` = SYSDATE() where `modified` > (SYSDATE() -3) and `situacao_id` in (2);` Mas não está funcionando a execução do SQL não da erros, mas não executa nenhuma ação.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE EVENT 
    evt_change_status ON SCHEDULE EVERY 24 HOUR 
    STARTS '2017-11-15 05:00:00' DO 
        UPDATE cadastros SET situacao_id = '1' WHERE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), modified) > 3;
```