# Como fazer para alterar o banco de dados MYSQL quando expirar data de 1 mês de cadastro

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho um cadastro de usuarios VIP que fazem um pagamento que o cadastro dura 1 mês.

Quando o pagamento é efetuado, a coluna status da tabela users_vip é atualizada para 1

```
id|iduser|datapedido|dataconfirm|datafinal |status
1 | 720  |2018-05-03|2018-05-03 |2018-06-03|  1
```

Gostaria de criar um controle, para que quando ele terminasse esse período de 1 mês que ele pagou, alterasse o status para 2, assim saberia que ele é registrado VIP, mas seu cadastro está inativo.

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 3):

De uma pesquisada sobre criação de eventos no MySQL

Um exemplo você pode ver aqui, e tente encaixar para seu problema
[Como criar evento diario no Mysql 5.6?
(Uma pergunta feita aqui no site)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/41467/como-criar-evento-diario-no-mysql-5-6)

**Editado:**

Para criação de um evento

```
CREATE
    [DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]
    EVENT
    [IF NOT EXISTS]
    event_name
    ON SCHEDULE schedule
    [ON COMPLETION [NOT] PRESERVE]
    [ENABLE | DISABLE | DISABLE ON SLAVE]
    [COMMENT 'comment']
    DO event_body;

schedule:
    AT timestamp [+ INTERVAL interval] ...
  | EVERY interval
    [STARTS timestamp [+ INTERVAL interval] ...]
    [ENDS timestamp [+ INTERVAL interval] ...]

interval:
    quantity {YEAR | QUARTER | MONTH | DAY | HOUR | MINUTE |
              WEEK | SECOND | YEAR_MONTH | DAY_HOUR | DAY_MINUTE |
              DAY_SECOND | HOUR_MINUTE | HOUR_SECOND | MINUTE_SECOND}
```

Você poderia criar um evento diário que irá validar se a data do dia é igual a data `datafinal` e se for alterar o seu status para 2

**Exemplo**

Um exemplo do teu caso seria +/- isso

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` EVENT `atualiza_clientes_vips`
    ON SCHEDULE
        EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2018-05-03 12:00:00'
    ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
    ENABLE
    COMMENT ''
    DO BEGIN
  update SUATABELA set status = 2
   where datafinal >= CURRENT_DATE()
END
```

Como ele começa hoje as 12hr, todo dia as 12hr ele será executado novamente

Comment: legal, vou dar uma lida, obrigado

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/165817)

Comment: @LeandroAngelo Irei tomar mais cuidado e seguir sua recomendação

Comment: aí eu colocaria isso sendo chamado por uma função no PHP, quando o cliente fizer o pagamento, isso?

Comment: O evento é criado no próprio banco de dados e o banco se encarrega de executar ele diariamente (se você criar o evento diário), logo você não precisaria chamar ele no php.

Comment: Favor conferir novamente a resposta e verifique o Exemplo

Comment: Obrigado! eu testei e deu esse erro: #1064 - Você tem um erro de sintaxe no seu SQL próximo a 'END' na linha 10

Comment: se você só copiou e colou o meu exemplo, esse erro é aquele famoso ERRO - Falta só o ; no fim do update